# How to separate specific data from a file Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have a clients info on a text in this format and order:

> "first_name","last_name","company_name","address","city","county","state","zip","phone1","phone2","email","web"

now if i want only Email address `"email"` or any of other info to be exported to new file or delete other info from the file and keep only the `"email"`.
how i can do that.
Thanks

Comment: Use a Spreadsheet program like excel or libreoffice calc. They have great features for reading in text files (aka csv). Once you have the file in the spreadsheet you can delete columns and save the modified file.  
If you really want to use an editor like notepad++ for this kind of work, you need to master regular expressions in order to match and and select the columns. And we are not even talking about the topic "comma used inside quotes".

Comment: You better use an unix tool like `sed`or `awk`, to achieve your result

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 10 comma-separated fields enclosed with double quotes before the *email* field.

You may use

**Find What**: `^(?:"[^"\r\n]*",){10}"([^"\r\n]*).*\R*`
**Replace With**: `$1`

**Details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `(?:"[^"\r\n]*",){10}` - 10 consecutive occurrences of:

  - `"` - a double quote
  - `[^"\r\n]*` - 0+ chars other than a double quote, CR and LF
  - `",`  - a `",` substring
- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"\r\n]*)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` backreference) matching 0+ chars other than a double quote, CR and LF
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\R*` - 0 or more line breaks.

[image]